# Track Configuration Pane in Cubase is GONE

Tags: cubase

[image]

A few weeks ago I was working on some project and I guess I hit a keyboard shortcut without knowing it, triggering the configuration pane usually left of the tracks list (I don't know what the terminology for any of this is) to just dissapear. It was fine at the time, but now I can't work without it.

What did I do? How can I re-enable the... thing that I disabled? I've tried opening other (older) projects, and the pane is there, but if I make a new project, it isn't. Clearly disabling it on one project makes it disabled on every project afterwards, but again, I don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't seen Cubase 5 in many years & it's changed a lot since, but isn't it this button, circled in red?

[image]

Comment: This is correct. And for the OP, it's called the 'Inspector'.

Comment: Oh jeez, I feel very idiotic for not figuring this out. Thanks for your help, guys!